# How to model a domain object that can be of several types (in several states)?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, architecture, domain-driven-design

Example : Having a human that can own 1 or more pets of different types (cat, dog, elephant, seal etc) .

I would think of making an aggregate that would have Human as root (that holds petCollection as reference to Pet) and another aggregate that would have Pet as root (with cat, dog, elephant, eagle as children for this aggregate) .

The problem is that each pet type can have different behaviour (example : a seal can swin() but it won't fly() / an eagle can fly() but it won't swim() ) . So a state or strategy pattern does not seem right . How can a human tell a pet object to run() if it doesn't know it's type ? Using the state/strategy pattern, the objects need to have similar behaviour . Doing an if/else (for the case of polymorphism to check the object type) check again , doesn't seem a proper design .

How should i design this domain or what patterns can help me here ?

Comment: Please describe a specific use case for this aggregate. For what reason do you want to iterate all pets and fire different methods on them?

Comment: Actually the domain is not about pets, it's a bit more complex , it regards some actions that came from a user interaction with some links . And i have this polymorphism problem in more aggregates .

Comment: Let me rethink the model and i will update somehow with a basic graph

Comment: Imagine that , polymorphism a problem :)

Comment: Before bringing patterns into play, you need to find a common interface that is known to the Human class. Difficult to tell in an abstract example, but maybe if you want to swim(), fly(), and run() you might just need to move(). If you cannot find a common interface, the relationship between Human and Pets might have to be modeled in a different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate roots and inheritance is not a very good idea typically.

You probably want to avoid one Aggregate to have a collection of other Aggregates.
The idea of the Aggregate (well, one of them) is that it represents *transaction boundary*, therefore there, ideally, should be no need in this structure.

It is normal, however, when one Aggregate has a collection of other Aggregates IDs.

Comment: "The root is the only member of the
AGGREGATE that outside objects are allowed to hold references to, although objects within the
boundary may hold references to each other." what eric evans says about aggregate roots . So they can hold references of other aggregate roots

Comment: But i agree with you about polymorphism in DDD +1 . In my case it is a problem, strategy or state would be better than polynrphism but it still doesnt feel right .

Comment: They can, there is no DDD police, it just may lead to unwanted situations that are hard to track of and to maintain. WHY would I hold a reference to another aggregate? The only reason is that I call its behavior. Then it means that the aggregate may change itself. Voila, we change two aggregates in one operation, which doesn't really comply to "transaction boundary" principle.

Comment: Yeah ideal is to have no referenccing that spans multiple aggregates . Ideal is to have transactions only inside aggregates and not outside of them (transactions that require several aggregates ) . But there is no ideal world . So yeah there might allways be transactions that span multiple aggregates .

Comment: Not ideally, but _typically_. _Typically_ (I mean very most of the cases) spanning transactions across aggregates happens because aggregates boundaries are not identified correctly. Often it is because people start with "database-first" approach (here is the User, here is the Order, etc) instead of identifying _behaviors_ and what data must mutate transactionally and forming aggregates this way. However you right, there are _some_ (rare) cases when touching >1 Aggregate is necessary. UnitOfWork (tran in domain services level) helps here.

Comment: What you are saying about referencing aggregate roots through root identiy VO does not go well with well defined baudaries . Myabe you are refering to the fact that some might say minimal aggregates with reference to others are good for scalability , but atually limits you to create well defined baudaries . And also will lead to higher database load .

Comment: Your answere kindof led me in the right direction . Though i still have alot to figure out wich way to go regarding the domain graph . Small aggregates with root id references , big aggregates with deep references . I hoped that there is a general solution but everything is relative when it comes to DDD :)

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, if something (only/always) *is* something, you should use Inheritance.

If something *does* something, you should use an Interface.

If something *plays the role* of something (e.g. a Legal Party plays the role of a Customer and/or a Supplier) you should use Composition.

So Seal inherits Animal and implements Swim, Bark

and

Dog inherits Animal and implements Run, Bark

If you want your animals to swim, then either iterate them checking if they implement Swim and then call swim(), or filter the collection prior to iterating through it to get the animals that implement Swim.

Comment: That's the whole thing about oop and domain driven design , not beign forced to run a big check for an object type . Something in my model is wrong , or i'm missing some objects . My objects have low cohesion .

Comment: @GeoC: what exactly do you want?  You said some animals respond to some requests but not to all.  So how do you propose dealing with that?  What happens if you send `swim()` to an eagle?  You either need a way to select only the animals that respond to a message and issue it to them - or you need to have all animals implement some kind of 'no-op' (which is generally not good practice).  Inheritance + interfaces specifically exist to help deal with just this type of situation.  There's nothing to stop you creating a filter method on the collection that returns only the subset that...

Comment: ...responds to a given interface though.  That at least saves each client having to repeat the filtering.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there's anything really architecture or DDD related here. It's just basic OO (polymorphism).

- If your starting point is a single pet and you want to trigger a behavior particular to its species, no secret - the caller has to know which subtype the pet is and reference the object with its real subtype, not `Pet`.
- If your starting point is a `Human` and you want to call some behavior across all or part of its pets, you need to reason about something more abstract.  If I understand the domain well, something like "an action that a human can tell an animal to perform".

  Once you've found the proper name for that, create an abstract method with that name on `Pet` and have every subclass of `Pet` implement it in its own way. Then, thanks to polymorphism, you can tell a collection of pets to do it regardless of whether they are cats, dogs, or elephants.